# flask генерация страниц

Tags: python, flask, site

Есть к примеру 192.168.0.150 и человек прибавил и получилось так 192.168.0.150/33274657843735,
мне нужно чтобы на странице вывелись эти цифры: типо чел заходит на сайт 192.168.0.150/33274657843735 и ему показываются 33274657843735, помогите плиз

Comment: На самой первой же странице документации https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/quickstart/#variable-rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код отображения айди

```
@app.route("/<int:id_user>")
def render_id_user(id_user):
    return str(id_user)
```